# Lazily loaded entities in `Object` methods: `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode`

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I created some model, for equipment, but I am not sure if I did correct mapping, also when I want to get rid of eager loading I got error:

```
"Type definition error: [simple type, class
org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested
exception is
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
serializer found for class
org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no
properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
chain:
java.util.ArrayList[0]-com.winterrent.winterrent.entity.ItemProperty[\"item\"]-com.winterrent.winterrent.entity.Item$HibernateProxy$RO0mkQSh[\"hibernateLazyInitializer\"])",
```

but if I change the fetch type to eager everything works fine.

My reverse engineering schema:
[image]

Then my entities:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "type")
    private ItemType itemType;

    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(ItemType itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ItemType getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    public void setItemType(ItemType itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", itemType=" + itemType +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Item item = (Item) o;
        return id == item.id &&
                Objects.equals(itemType, item.itemType);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, itemType);
    }
}
```

2)

```
public enum ItemType {
    SKI, BOARD
}
```

3)

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item_property_definition")
public class ItemPropertyDefinition {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "property_name")
    private String propertyName;

    @Column(name = "type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ItemType itemType;

    public ItemPropertyDefinition() {
    }

    public ItemPropertyDefinition(String propertyName, ItemType itemType) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPropertyName() {
        return propertyName;
    }

    public void setPropertyName(String propertyName) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public ItemType getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    public void setItemType(ItemType itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ItemPropertyDefinition{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", propertyName='" + propertyName + '\'' +
                ", itemType=" + itemType +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ItemPropertyDefinition that = (ItemPropertyDefinition) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals(propertyName, that.propertyName) &&
                Objects.equals(itemType, that.itemType);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, propertyName, itemType);
    }
}
```

And finally mapping:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item_properties")
public class ItemProperty {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    private Item item;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_property_definition_id")
    private ItemPropertyDefinition itemPropertyDefinition;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    public ItemProperty(){}

    public ItemProperty(Item item, ItemPropertyDefinition itemPropertyDefinition, String value) {
        this.item = item;
        this.itemPropertyDefinition = itemPropertyDefinition;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public ItemPropertyDefinition getItemPropertyDefinition() {
        return itemPropertyDefinition;
    }

    public void setItemPropertyDefinition(ItemPropertyDefinition itemPropertyDefinition) {
        this.itemPropertyDefinition = itemPropertyDefinition;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ItemProperty{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", item=" + item +
                ", itemPropertyDefinition=" + itemPropertyDefinition +
                ", value='" + value + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ItemProperty that = (ItemProperty) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals(item, that.item) &&
                Objects.equals(itemPropertyDefinition, that.itemPropertyDefinition) &&
                Objects.equals(value, that.value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, item, itemPropertyDefinition, value);
    }
}
```

Thank you for the hints. It's my first playing around with backend.

Comment: Could you write exactly what you are doing, when the error occurs?

Comment: @Andronicus if I have @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    private Item item;   ->> fetch type lazy then it occurs, if eager everything is ok

Comment: On startup or when executing a query?

Comment: @Andronicus when executing query, I guess mapping is wrong...

Comment: Then post that query, please. I need to see exactly, what you are doing.

Comment: @Andronicus 
    public List<ItemProperty> findAll() {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query<ItemProperty> theQuery =
                currentSession.createQuery("from ItemProperty", ItemProperty.class);
        List<ItemProperty> itemProperties = theQuery.getResultList();
        return itemProperties;
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding `toString()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods using entities. Everything, that is used inside those functions need to be basic entities, that are loaded together with parent entity. That is why there was no exception was thrown, when loaded eagerly.

In general I wouldn't recommend using child entities to determine equality and so on as, for example, this requires them to be loaded eagerly, which is not good for performance. I would leave them lazily loaded and rewrite overridden methods for performance sake, but if you need them used in those methods, you need to load them eagerly.

Vlad Mihalcea wrote a good [read](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) about implementing `toString()`, `equals` and `hashCode()`.